# StringJoin Dynamic problem

Tags: dynamic, string-manipulation

My goal is to import a XML file from the site fueleconomy.gov to get a list of cars dependent on the year given as the user input .

Here is the code:

```
years = Import["http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/year", "XML"];
y = Cases[years, XMLElement["menuItem", _, _], Infinity] /. 
    XMLElement[_, _, {val_}] ->  val /. 
   XMLElement["menuItem", _, list_] -> list;
Do[y[[i]] = DeleteDuplicates[y[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[y], 1}];
years = y[[All, 1]]
PopupMenu[Dynamic[year], years]

makes = Import[
   StringJoin[
    "http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/make?year=", 
    year], "XML"];
```

I tried to put `Dynamic[year]` instead of year but it crashes en got this error:

> "String expected at position 2 in
>
> http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/make?year=<>2014"

My question is why `StringJoin` put '<>' in the url in the error message. I used the same function before and it worked, any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that `Dynamic` puts an invisible wrapper around its argument so that `StringJoin` does not see it as a String anymore. `year` itself is a number and no String, so you should use `ToString`on it. The `<>` in the error message is simply the infix form of `StringJoin` (see its doc page).

Comment: Yes, I watched it, the solution gived by the page don't work it says that ToString[exp] solved it but if I do that with my variable it return Dynamic[year] and no the value

Comment: Which page are you referring to? As I wrote in my above comment you cant use Dynamic[year] where a string is expected as that simply isn't a string. If I replace year in your last line with ToString[year] the code works.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html  

I see this references and year is a string the xml file have two elements text and value and i get text
Also i try to put Dynamic[..] englobing makes =Import[...] and it works

Comment: You don't write this in your question, but is your intention to have the `makes` variable updated automatically when the user selects a new year from the pop-up menu?

Comment: Sorry, yes that's my idea

Comment: Well, have a look at my answer below then.

Comment: Please see specifically: [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85491/121).  Many people misunderstand `Dynamic`.  I was surely one of them.  It is a true "pitfall" IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Moving it to a `Manipulate` sounds like a better idea:

```
Manipulate[
 makes = Import[
   StringJoin[
    "http://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/make?year=", 
    ToString@year], "XML"];
 Row[{"Loaded car makes for the year ", 
   Style[ToString[year], {FontFamily -> "Arial", Large, Red}]}],
 {year, Reverse@years}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Okey thanks it works

Comment: if I want to put make at other dropdowm and update data depend of year selected:  i have to make {make, Reverse@makes}, or its impossible?